# Cant get compiled typescript to work inside html

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I am working on an app using electron framework. My project is structured like this.

```
project
  |----scripts
  |  |----model.ts
  |  |----view.ts
  |  |----controller
  |  |----tsconfig.json
  |----index.html
  |----style.css
  |----main.js
  |----node_modules
  |----package.json
```

In the typescript files I am importing some modules like below

```
import fs = require("fs");
import Electron = require("electron");
```

I have compiled it with different `tsconfig.json` settings. I want to be able to include the compiled java-script file inside the `index.html`. Here is an example `tsconfig.json` that i used. I have tried different values for `module` option.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
       "module" : "amd",
       "target": "es5",
       "outFile" : "result.js",
       "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
       "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I always get `exports` is undefined reference or `define` is undefined reference etc. I really want to use typescript instead of plain java-script. I have gone through a lot of similar questions on stack overflow to no avail.

Comment: How are you running this? In the browser or as an Electron app?

Comment: @Saravana As an electron app.